# What is the purpose of copying an object in object oriented programming?

Tags: oop, object, constructor, deep-copy

I've been learning c# for about 3 months now and one thing I have come across today is the concept of deep and shallow copy constructors on objects (having just gotten used to the concepts of base classes, inheritance and instantiation – polymorphism still hasn't’ really sunk in yet to be honest… I digress).

My first thought when seeing a copy deep constructor on a base class (in this case, a user class) was “why on earth would you make a copy of an object?”. The articles I've looked at explain how to do it and how it works, but I still haven’t been able to find any practical examples of *why you would do it*. If I had a class of person, surely I’d just create a new instance of the person class?

I appreciate there is probably something fundamental I'm missing here but if anyone can fill the gaps that would be great. A real life of example demonstrating the usefulness of it would be even better! Cheers!

Comment: I recommend to use cloning only in case of template class, not for those class which basically come under inheritance bcos `class` might having different event trigger in `constructor` and having abstract method/property number of thing one should keep in mind. `Serialization` is also another factor which normally taken in account while cloning of any reference value type object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many situations where you might need to duplicate an object.

- **For convenience:** When you create an object, you usually need to initialize it, either in the form of calling methods to set values, or in the form of passing parameters to the constructor. Sometimes, performing all this initialization might amount to a lot of work.  If you want a new object B which only differs from another object A by a single value, then it may be easier to get a copy of A as B and change a single value of B, rather than to create B from scratch.
- **Because logic requires it:** When a chess playing algorithm wants to make its next move, it may internally make many copies of the current board, modify each one of them with one of many possible moves that it may make, evaluate each one of the new boards using some heuristics, pick the best, and then use that as the new current board.
- **To be defensive:** When a `Person` object is asked for its `DateOfBirth`, it may not necessarily return a reference to its own `DateOfBirth`, because someone might then alter the `Date` object, thus altering the Person's `DateOfBirth`. So, the `Person` object is likely to return a *defensive copy* of its `DateOfBirth`.
- **To take a snapshot:** If I have a list of event observers to invoke, I might want to take a (shallow) *snapshot copy* of the list before starting to invoke the observers, because an observer may decide to unregister itself while I am processing the list, which will have disastrous consequences.  (`ConcurrentModificationException`, look it up.)

Answer (score 2):

If you simply copy an object by reference you get:

```
Whatever a = new Whatever();

Whatever b = a;

a.myField = "stuff";
```

you end up with b.myField also containing "stuff". This is because it's the exact same object.

However, if you're creating a prototype object that you'd like to maintain independently, then you need to copy the fields over in a deep copy.

Example

```
Car priusPrototype = new Car("Toyota", "myModel"); //etc.

Car myPrius = priusPrototype.clone();
Car neighboursPrius = priusPrototype.clone();

myPrius.regNumber ="AB14 33ND";
```

the neighbours Prius is unaltered as myPrius is a separate object.

This is a contrived example, you'd probably use a factory in this instance, but it's an example of where you'd have things with *almost* the same fields, but you need to maintain independence.

Answer (score 0):

> If I had a class of person, surely I’d just create a new instance of the person class?

What if you want that second instance of Person to also have the same name, same age, same everything?

The process of duplicating an object so that you end up with two instances that represent the same state (but are independent of each-other) is called cloning or copying.

In some cases, you can do that manually by creating a new instance and calling all the necessary setters, but sometimes they are not all exposed in the public interface. Either way, it's a copy.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor is a special constructor that initializes a new object from an existing object.Compiler will creates a default copy constructor which copies your class data bit by bit, if you wont create it.Then why we have to re-create a Copy constructor?consider this class(not a professional code).

```
Class A
{
    public int *p;
    A(){ p = new int;}
    ~A(){
         delete p;
     }
};
int main()
{
   A a;
   A b = a; //default copy constructor provided by compiler,which exactly copies a.p pointer to to b.p;
   return 0;
};
```

But there is one big problem.when main is going to die,it will clean all stack variables.So may be first "a" destructor will be called and "a.p" is deleted.Next b destructor will be called,which again tries to delete b.p which is already deleted in a(Note thst a.p and b.p pointes same pointer).This will cause an run time error.To overcome this problem we have to create a copy aonstructor and Assignement operator(which is called in different scenarios).So the Class A copy constructor will be,
Collapse | Copy Code

```
class A::A(const class A& RefA)
{
   p = new int;    // create a new p 
   *p = *RefA.p; // copy the value
}
```

So now both a, b in the above example will have different p pointers.Assignement operator functionality is also same.But there aim is defferent.

There are three general cases where the copy constructor is called instead of the assignment operator:

- When instantiating one object and initializing it with values from
  another object (as in the example above).
- When passing an object by
  value.
- When an object is returned from a function by value.

In other cases like,

```
A a;
a = b;
```

an Assignment operator is called

Credits to the answer go to  వేంకటనారాయణ(venkatmakam)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have clear in mind the difference between shallow copy and deep copy.

**Shallow copy** is a copy of the only reference to the original instance. So basically, working on the copy you are still working on the same original instance, shared among different references. This could be useful in some situation when you need to share a single object, or when you have a complex object that is difficult and "performance-killing" to deep copy . But sharing instances could be dangerous in some situation, and often extra work is needed to design thread-safe classes.

**Deep copy** instead produces a new instance. So you have multiple objects (and not different references to the same object) having the same state, but living indipendently. So in this case changing the state of the copied instance doesn't reflects on the state of the original object.

A deep copy is also the basis of the [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) creational pattern.